# How to constraint type of abstract class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

This is what I want to do:

```
abstract class AbBase
  static newDerived<T extends typeof AbBase>(this: T) {
    return class A extends this {
      //...
    }
  }
```

Essentially I want newDerived to only be called from non-abstract implementations.

However, I get this error on the `extends this` part:
"Type 'T' is not a constructor function type. Did you mean for T to be constrained to type 'new (...args: any[]) => AbBase'?"

But then if I do

```
  static newDerived<T extends typeof AbBase>(this: new (...args: any[]) => AbstractInstanceType<T>) {
```

it says, "Base constructor return type 'AbstractInstanceType' is not an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members."

Answer (score 1):

You can constrain `T` to be a constructor that returns `AbBase`. This will solve both the non-abstract class requirement and will satisfy the compiler that this can be inherited:

```
abstract class AbBase {
    static newDerived<T extends { new (...a: any[]) : Pick<AbBase, keyof AbBase> } >(this: T) {
        return class A extends this {

        }
    }
}

AbBase.newDerived() // error

class Derived extends AbBase {}
Derived.newDerived() // ok
```

Comment: That requires me to implement the abstract members in A, but I want to only be able to extend 'this' for those that already implement all the abstract types

Comment: I also end up not being able to refer to static members of 'this' in newDerived()

Comment: @NathanielTucker I fixed the requirement to reimplement the abstract methods, using `Pick` it's not ideal but since the constructor returns an abstract type the compiler requires us to reimplement all abstract methods. The static issue I'm not sure how to fix, if I and anything to the constraint the compiler will not let us derive from `this` anymore. The way mixins are build in TS is a bit frail: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743

Comment: @NathanielTucker FYI I think the requirement to implement the members in the mixin class is a bug, I filed it as such: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29653